Showing DAW Reaper in QJackCtl
With my previous Ubuntu (I guess it was 22.04, but I am not sure about it as I have 22.04 also now), when I started my DAW Reaper, the application was shown in the graph of QJackCtl, which was great because I could connect the outputs to other applications like SuperCollider.
After I reinstalled Ubuntu (currently 22.04), I do the same and the DAW Reaper is not shown anymore in my QJackCtl, but SuperCollider is. Anybody knows some way to make Reaper appear?

Go to preferences, and choose Jack as the device
